# PHP - how to display customized page url in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am using Windows IIS 7 with PHP and MySQL.

Whenever someone opens an account on my website, he/she will also create one store ID like `MyHawaiiSpa`. Once this store ID is generated, it can not be changed. Here I have assumed the `pkid` of this account is 1.

Now, a visitor clicks the `MyHawaiiSpa` store link from the home page.  The visitor will be sent to `shop.php` where all items belonging to `MyHawaiiSpa` will be displayed. By clicking on any product on the `MyHawaiiSpa` store, the `product.php` page will open, where product details are displayed.

Currently, I have managed it using `querystring` in PHP. so each store is distinguished like this: `mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?sid=1`.

My question is now this: I would like visitor clicks on the `MyHawaiiSpa` store link from the home page, so that the visitor will see `mywebsite.com/user/MyHawaiiSpa/shop.php` instead of `mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?sid=1` (which I have already done now.)

The solution I was thinking of was this: Whenever someone opens an account and creates their store ID, the folder `MyHawaiiSpa` will be created and the `shop.php` as well as the `product.php` pages will be copied under the `MyHawaiiSpa` folder programmatically. This process will be repeated for all stores those are going to be created.

Is there any other way to do this so I don't need to create a folder and copy files for each store and still I can get desired result I just explained above?

Comment: use .htaccess for url rewritting

Comment: As its Windows IIS, add it in your web.config. http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: Hello Jithin, Thank you for your reply. Can you please show me very basic example of how to write code in Web.Config to convert url like mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?mid=1 or mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?mid=1&sid=MyHawaiiSpa to mywebsite.com/user/MyHawaiiSpa... There after I will go according to your help. I am really sorry but right now I can't understand how to start this after referring link you provided in your comment. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it bad idea to copy PHP file when someone registered, it will be mess to maintain it in long term, you just need to store the ID `MyHawaiiSpa` as unique key in database. and use `store id` as slug in URL.

since you are using IIS here is good read to rewrite URL

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/provide-url-rewriting-functionality

1. You can learn `.htaccess` mod_rewrite from [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/)
2. and then you can covert these rules to `IIS7` friendly using [this link](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please show me very basic example of how to write code in Web.Config to convert url like mywebsite.com/user/shop.php?sid=1 to mywebsite.com/user/MyHawaiiSpa... There after I will go according to your help. I am really sorry but right now I can't understand how to start this.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is an .htaccess rewrite which will allow you to turn your query into an SEO-friendly url and still read properly when called on that page.

[Here is apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

A basic example of a rewrite to force all requests through the index page unless they are a real folder or file would be something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.|^$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

To do a similar rewrite on a windows server you would need to edit a `web.config` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL rewriting . It is very easy to learn and implement.

On linux servers it is done using a file call .htaccess. On IIS I think file is called 
web.config

Basically what this does is, you configure it to show one url while in reality you go to another url.

These links should get you up and running fast

http://www.robbagby.com/php/php-and-iis-running-php-under-fast-cgi-and-url-rewriting/

http://salopek.eu/content/26/introduction-to-url-rewriting-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-and-regular-expressions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guzJWqNJ3DA&feature=channel

http://www.phpgenious.com/2010/04/url-rewriting-with-php-and-iis-7/

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/provide-url-rewriting-functionality